# GMP, multiple definitions of function

Tags: c, gcc

I've these simple source files:

Header file

```
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void test_uint_to_mpz();

#endif
```

Implementation file

```
//src.c
#include "header.h"

void test_uint_to_mpz() {

   char hex_string[200];
   uint64_t var;
   mpz_t mpz_var;
   mpz_init(mpz_var);

   printf("Please enter a hex string that fits a variable uint64_t : ");
   scanf("%s",hex_string);

   var = (uint64_t)strtol(hex_string,NULL,16);
   mpz_set_ui(mpz_var,var);

   printf("Your input value was: %llx\n",var);
   printf("The mpz equivalent is: ");
   mpz_out_str(stdout,16,mpz_var);
   printf("\n");

   mpz_clear(mpz_var);

}
```

Main

```
//main.c
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   test_uint_to_mpz();

   return 0;
}
```

Then I try to compile using this simple line:

```
gcc src.c main.c -L/user/lcg/lib -o numericalTest -I./ -lgmp -O3 -static
```

Since I want to use a static linking. To me is fine, I'm quite sure that the installation of gmp is fine (see the -L option in my command line).

However then I have:

```
gcc src.c main.c -L/user/lcg/lib -o numericalTest -I./ -lgmp -O3 -static
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_abs':
main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__gmpz_abs'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_fits_uint_p':
main.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `__gmpz_fits_uint_p'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x20): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_fits_ulong_p':
main.c:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `__gmpz_fits_ulong_p'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x60): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_fits_ushort_p':
main.c:(.text+0x70): multiple definition of `__gmpz_fits_ushort_p'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x70): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_get_ui':
main.c:(.text+0xb0): multiple definition of `__gmpz_get_ui'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0xb0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_getlimbn':
main.c:(.text+0xd0): multiple definition of `__gmpz_getlimbn'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0xd0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_neg':
main.c:(.text+0x110): multiple definition of `__gmpz_neg'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x110): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_perfect_square_p':
main.c:(.text+0x130): multiple definition of `__gmpz_perfect_square_p'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x130): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_popcount':
main.c:(.text+0x150): multiple definition of `__gmpz_popcount'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x150): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_set_q':
main.c:(.text+0x180): multiple definition of `__gmpz_set_q'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x180): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpz_size':
main.c:(.text+0x190): multiple definition of `__gmpz_size'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x190): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpq_abs':
main.c:(.text+0x1a0): multiple definition of `__gmpq_abs'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x1a0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpq_neg':
main.c:(.text+0x1c0): multiple definition of `__gmpq_neg'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x1c0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpn_add':
main.c:(.text+0x1e0): multiple definition of `__gmpn_add'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x1e0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpn_add_1':
main.c:(.text+0x360): multiple definition of `__gmpn_add_1'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x360): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpn_cmp':
main.c:(.text+0x570): multiple definition of `__gmpn_cmp'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x570): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpn_sub':
main.c:(.text+0x5a0): multiple definition of `__gmpn_sub'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x5a0): first defined here
/tmp/ccz2qa8j.o: In function `__gmpn_sub_1':
main.c:(.text+0x720): multiple definition of `__gmpn_sub_1'
/tmp/cc0jVOgJ.o:src.c:(.text+0x720): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [output] Error 1
```

Where could be the problem?

Update: i post the makefile

```
CC=gcc
SRCS=src.c main.c
HEADER=header.h
OBJ_FILES=$(addsuffix ./,(basename $(SRCS)))
INCLUDES=-I./
FLAG=-lgmp -O3
output : $(SRCS) $(HEADER)
    $(CC) $(SRCS) -L/user/lcg/lib -o numericalTest $(INCLUDES) $(FLAG) -static
clean :
    rm *.o
```

Comment: Delete all of the object files prior the compilation

Comment: BTW, the function should be defined as `void test_uint_to_mpz(void)`

Comment: I am not sure if that helps, but having all includes in the header file is IMHO redundant. You can/should move those includes to the implementation file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There was one object file, I deleted such file, it still doesn't work. Should the (void) make any difference?

Comment: It compiles fine for me.  Could be a problem with your GMP installation.

Comment: Are these the full files you have? Or you removed something?

Comment: Is there a way to check if it properly installed? (at this point... I guess that is the problem).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just added the makefile

Comment: Which version of `gmp` are you using?

Comment: 6.1.0, I wonder if I'm missing some prerequisites

Comment: I am also getting same errors. Would you please help to fix it.

Comment: @DeepakIngole Is it the same problem?

Comment: Yes, how did you fixed it.

Comment: I can exactly remember now, neither the problem I had. If you can give more details of what are you doing right now maybe I can help.

Comment: Do you have a makefile you can somehow share?